# i cant fetch the value of $speciality FROM THE TABLE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$qry = "SELECT `$speciality` FROM `graph`";
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a variable for the column name? How are you setting it?

Comment: YES ITS A VARIABLE $speciality = 'OBS';

Comment: please share $speciality variable intialization

Comment: Don't yell please.

Comment: $speciality = "OBS";

Comment: Do you have a column named OBS?

Comment: yes i have it in database,

Comment: but when in place of $speciality i am using OBS thn it is working...ths what is the isue??

Comment: Then try `$qry = "SELECT ".$speciality." FROM graph"`

Comment: Also check if it is working when you put OBS value directly without variable

Comment: Could you provide is with more information, what isn't working? do you get an error message or does it just return nothing? what is the code around the query looking like? have you turned on both error reporting and are echoing MySQL errors?

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or heavily downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. You should [read this before you post your next one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove back-tick from your code around column name:-

```
$speciality = 'OBS'; 
echo $qry = "SELECT `".$speciality."` FROM graph";

Output:- SELECT `OBS` FROM graph
```

***Note:- It strange because As @Jay says you code is working fine too, and now I check it too and it works fine. So I think may be something wrong in your next line of code. So check yourself. Thanks.***

Comment: Remove back ticks? That's not correct. PHP will interpolate the variable properly.

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion, it was a question.

Comment: The back ticks are OK, no need to remove them. And don't yell @Anant, I can hear you perfectly well.

Comment: Test the OP's code, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Could you change the code so that after executing the query you display the possible error

```
mysql_query($qry, $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";
```

this way you can see what goes wrong in the mysql code.

Also you're easily vulnerable to SQL injection attacks by inserting a variable in the query the way you are now.

Edit based on your comment that it is not the MySQL:

Also add `error_reporting(-1);` at the beginning of your php code to display any other errors. and use `var_dump` or `print_r` on suspicious variables to check what their value really is. This is the basics of debugging any php code.